# Are these terminal commands and temporarily disable SIP safe?

Tags: terminal, sip

Im trying to installed Sophos anti virus on a mac running 10.10.5, but it keeps failing to install, Sophos support have advised i should do the following work flow, which involves running the following terminal commands and temporarily turning off SIP.

Is the following workflow safe to do ?

```
1. Reboot into Recovery Mode (Command+R on boot) 
2. Open Utilities->Terminal 
3. Run the command (This turns off SIP): csrutil disable 
4. Reboot 
5. Open a Terminal, run the following 3 commands:

sudo chmod 755 /
sudo chmod 755 /Library/
sudo chmod 755 /Library/Application\ Support/

6. Install Sophos Home 
7. Repeat Step 1 & 2 
8. Run the command (This turns on SIP): csrutil enable
```

Comment: Can you add the link describing the instructions?

Comment: OS X 10.10 doesn't have SIP. It was introduced in 10.11. My bet is Sophos simply isn't compatible with 10.10 - https://support.home.sophos.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005339243-System-requirements-for-installing-Sophos-Home

Comment: @NimeshNeema it was an email from support

Comment: Generally I would take such advise sent over email with a grain of salt, especially in case of such sensitive software as anti-virus. (Simply put, I wouldn't follow these steps)

Comment: @Tetsujin it dose indeed seems it isnt supported with 10.10 , although it was up until very recently as when i first tried to install it about 6-8 weeks ago i checked and it was compatible with 10.10